# How do I keep updated the data in my web page?

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, synchronization

I have a webapp implemented with google apps script. There is a web page that shows a table with part of the content of a google spreadsheet. I would like to know how I can detect changes in the data source without having to continually check it on the client side with setInverval function. I'm looking for something more efficient. It's possible? Thank you.

Note: Currently, I use setInterval but I think that this option consumes network and server resources innecesarily.

Comment: If the changes occur due user edits then you can use onEdit().  onChange() can detect some import types with "OTHER"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I need is to detect on the server side changes in the database and send updates to all clients connected to the application. Is it possible with a GAS WebApp?

Comment: There no trigger for changes caused by formulas and other scripts.  If they did I suspect Google Servers would be highly susceptible to DDOS attacks.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will continue to check the server periodically for updates.